# How do you change the VideoPlayer Fullscreen Mode to Landscape instead of Portrait

Tags: flutter, dart

I want my videoplayer fullscreen to be in landscape mode when entering Full Screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/auto_orientation and https://pub.dev/packages/chewie 
In `initState()` of `_VideoScaffoldState` do `AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode();`

code snippet

```
_chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
        aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        autoPlay: true,
        looping: true,
        routePageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondAnimation, provider) {
          return AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: animation,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return VideoScaffold(
              
...
class _VideoScaffoldState extends State<VideoScaffold> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
    AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode();
    super.initState();
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:auto_orientation/auto_orientation.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:chewie/src/chewie_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChewieDemo(),
  );
}

class ChewieDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  ChewieDemo({this.title = 'Chewie Demo'});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ChewieDemoState();
  }
}

class _ChewieDemoState extends State<ChewieDemo> {
  TargetPlatform _platform;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController1;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController2;
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController1 = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4');
    _videoPlayerController2 = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_20mb.mp4');
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
        aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        autoPlay: true,
        looping: true,
        routePageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondAnimation, provider) {
          return AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: animation,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return VideoScaffold(
                child: Scaffold(
                  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
                  body: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    child: provider,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
        // Try playing around with some of these other options:

        // showControls: false,
        // materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
        //   playedColor: Colors.red,
        //   handleColor: Colors.blue,
        //   backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        //   bufferedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
        // ),
        // placeholder: Container(
        //   color: Colors.grey,
        // ),
        // autoInitialize: true,
        );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController1.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController2.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: widget.title,
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        platform: _platform ?? Theme.of(context).platform,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: Chewie(
                  controller: _chewieController,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _chewieController.enterFullScreen();
              },
              child: Text('Fullscreen'),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _chewieController.dispose();
                        _videoPlayerController2.pause();
                        _videoPlayerController2.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 0));
                        _chewieController = ChewieController(
                          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
                          aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          looping: true,
                        );
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Video 1"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _chewieController.dispose();
                        _videoPlayerController1.pause();
                        _videoPlayerController1.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 0));
                        _chewieController = ChewieController(
                          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController2,
                          aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          looping: true,
                        );
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: Text("Video 2"),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _platform = TargetPlatform.android;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Android controls"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _platform = TargetPlatform.iOS;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: Text("iOS controls"),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VideoScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoScaffold({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _VideoScaffoldState();
}

class _VideoScaffoldState extends State<VideoScaffold> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
    AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    AutoOrientation.portraitAutoMode();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it start in landscape mode because right now it only starts in portraits. Thanks for you time by the way.

Comment: you can directly cal await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);

Comment: where would I await since you cant do it in initState

Comment: you can replace your main() with the following code. Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly then -
You can create an event on the fullscreen icon(assuming you have an icon to identify fullscreen mode) and take leverage of flutter's **OrientationBuilder** widget.

A sample would be like below code, which I used for my own project. Please note key, backgroundColor properties are not required for OrientationBuilder widget. It was my project requirements.

```
return Scaffold(
  key: _homeKey,
  backgroundColor: bodyBackground,
  body: OrientationBuilder(
    builder: (context, orientation) {
      return Container(
        child: orientation == Orientation.portrait
            ? _potraitView()
            : _landscapeView(),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

You can then create your own widget inside **_landscapeView()** (for example) return may be a Container with width an height to fit the screen.

Something like

```
Widget _landscapeView() {
  return Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: <Your design specs>
);
```

Hope that will help !!
Good luck